# Post woocommerce total to payment processor

Tags: php, woocommerce, payment

I've been given the task of setting up a payment processor for my boss who uses Moneris in Canada. I need to use their form to post the price but unsure what the best method is and have little to no back-end WordPress experience.
I need to assign the woocommerce cart total to the input "charge_total" value on the form submit.

Sample Form:

```
<form action="https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php" method="POST"><input name="ps_store_id" type="HIDDEN" value="XXXX" />

    <input name="hpp_key" type="HIDDEN" value="XXXX" />
    <input name="charge_total" type="HIDDEN" value="1" />

    <input name="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT" value="Click to proceed to Secure Page" />

</form>
```

Comment: don't DIY if you have little to no experience. use https://woocommerce.com/products/moneris-gateway/

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper Unfortunately we are just looking to use Moneris' hosted pay page and not do any of the processing and storing of CC info onsite. I do plan on reading through my PHP and wordpress dev books but this has a deadline way closer than the time it would take for me to learn and develope it myself!

Comment: posted an answer, but i dont feel it will help you or that business in general to do it this way. you will have trouble having payment notifications, there is no wp integration to the moneris api and the api is scarcely documented. therefore i will let you assume that if the client clicks proceed, you manually check incoming payments and process the order status manually from the admin panel.

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper Thanks, I was actually just attempting this through a custom page with a plugin that allows php on the front end but my result at the payment processor is coming up blank, I manipulated the value with javascript but I'm unsure how to integrate that with php.  The way it works right now is they leave when they hit the submit button and input CC info on the following page which generates a receipt and emails it to them then redirects to my thank you page.

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper This is the link I have for the payment processors documentation(they were no help when I called, they basically said go to our dev center where I dug to find this! )https://developer.moneris.com/en/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/Hosted%20Solutions/Hosted%20Payment%20Page

Comment: edited my answer. might be more of a plug and play deal now but it would help me if you could just tell me on what page you need to insert this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your template where the form is generated.
your sample form would become

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$cartTotal=$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total()
?>

<form action="https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php" method="POST">
    <input name="ps_store_id" type="HIDDEN" value="XXXX" />

    <input name="hpp_key" type="HIDDEN" value="XXXX" />
    <input name="charge_total" type="HIDDEN" value="<?php echo $cartTotal?>" />

    <input name="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT" value="Click to proceed to Secure Page" />

</form>
```

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php is your main checkout file. i do not know where in the checkout process you wish to allow the user to leave the site, but i assume it would be form-pay.php

Good day, hope it helps you out

edit:

after conversation in comments, i would point you towards using the hooks. i will be using the after checkout hook to inject some html in there but if you let me know where you need the code ill re edit the hook for the proper position

put this in the functions.php file in your enabled theme

```
function add_custom_html() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cartTotal=$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total()


    $my_custom_form = '<form action="https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php" method="POST">
        <input name="ps_store_id" type="HIDDEN" value="XXXX" />

        <input name="hpp_key" type="HIDDEN" value="XXXX" />
        <input name="charge_total" type="HIDDEN" value="'&$cartTotal&'"/>

        <input name="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT" value="Click to proceed to Secure Page" />

    </form>';
    echo $my_custom_form;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'add_custom_html');
```